# Homework: Morse code to English characters

Tags: c, morse-code

In the following code only the first `.` or `-` are picked up and it doesn't match to any of the letters defined in the switch statements below.  Any idea how I can change it to see the entire Morse letters?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (void){

    char str[20]=".-/.-/.-";
    int i;
    char letter;


//  printf("%s is %d long", str,strlen(str));


    for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
    
        switch(str[i]){ 
                            /*switch statements set out decimal values for Hex digits*/
            case '.-':
                letter ='A';
                break;
            case '-...':
                letter = 'B';
                break;
            case '-.-.':
                letter = 'C';
                break;
            case '-..':
                return 'D';
                break;
            case '.':
                letter = 'E';
                break;
            case '..-.':
                letter = 'F';
                break;
            case '--.':
                letter = 'G';
                break;
            case '....':
                letter = 'H';
                break;
            case '..':
                letter = 'I';
                break;
            case '.---':
                letter = 'J';
                break;
            case '-.-.':
                letter = 'K';
                break;
            case '.-..':
                letter = 'L';
                break;
            case '--':
                letter = 'M';
                break;
            case '-.':
                letter = 'N';
                break;
            case '---':
                letter = 'O';
                break;
            case '.--.':
                letter = 'P';
                break;
            case '--.-':
                letter = 'Q';
                break;
            case '.-.':
                letter = 'R';
                break;
            case '...':
                letter = 'S';
                break;
            case '-':
                letter = 'T';
                break;
            case '..-':
                letter = 'U';
                break;
            case '...-':
                letter = 'V';
                break;
            case '.--':
                letter = 'W';
                break;
            case '-..-':
                letter = 'X';
                break;
            case '-.--':
                letter = 'Y';
                break;
            case '--..':
                letter = 'Z';
                break;
            default:
            printf("Something went wrong\n");
            break;
    }

}
printf("%d",letter);
}
```

I tried changing the single quotes `''` I had initially for the Morese codes to double quotes `""` for strings, but I can only pick up the first `-` or `.` in it either way.

Comment: Two problems: 1: `'.-'` -> `".-"`. Strings are not the same thing as characters. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C learning material. 2: But anyway,  you cannot use switch/case on strings, that works only with scalar types. For comparing strings you need to use `strcmp` (also in the chapter mentioned before)

Comment: And your for loop makes no sense whatsoever. You don't handle the `/` separator at all.

Comment: What does "switch statements set out decimal values for Hex digits" mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you get compiler warnings when you used multibyte character literals? If you get any warning or error message from your compiler you should include it into your question.

Comment: You probably need to isolate the letters, e.g. by replacing the `/` with a null byte, or by making a copy of the letter up to but not including the `/` and then null-terminating the copy, and then use an array rather than a switch to identify which letter or digit or punctuation you have isolated.

Comment: @Dave Anderson 1) New code is **not** going to work.  `".-"".-"".-"` is same as `".-.-.-"`.  Same as packed AAA and RK.  2) Poor SO etiquette to change code once answers arrive.  Please revert you edit.

Comment: Code rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

You can't `switch` on strings in C. The `case` statement must be a constant expression, and a string literal does not count as such.

You could either `switch` on each individual letter (which would produce 5 levels of switches where `-`, `.` and `\0` need to be handled) or you could do something simpler, like converting each letter to a numeric value:

```c
int toValue(const char *m) {
    int value = 0;
    for (; *m; ++m) {
        value *= 3;
        switch (*m) {
            case '-':
                value += 2;
                break;
            case '.':
                value += 1;
                break;
            default:
                return -1;  // error
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

And then `switch` on that:

Example:

```c
char fromMorse(const char *m) {
    switch (toValue(m)) {
        case  5: return 'A';    // .-
        case 67: return 'B';    // -...
        case 70: return 'C';    // -.-.
        case 22: return 'D';    // -..
        case  1: return 'E';    // .
        case 43: return 'F';    // ..-.
        case 25: return 'G';    // --.
        case 40: return 'H';    // ....
        case  4: return 'I';    // ..
        case 53: return 'J';    // .---
        case 23: return 'K';    // -.-
        case 49: return 'L';    // .-..
        case  8: return 'M';    // --
        case  7: return 'N';    // -.
        case 26: return 'O';    // ---
        case 52: return 'P';    // .--.
        case 77: return 'Q';    // --.-
        case 16: return 'R';    // .-.
        case 13: return 'S';    // ...
        case  2: return 'T';    // -
        case 14: return 'U';    // ..-
        case 41: return 'V';    // ...-
        case 17: return 'W';    // .--
        case 68: return 'X';    // -..-
        case 71: return 'Y';    // -.--
        case 76: return 'Z';    // --..
        default: return -1;     // error
    }
}
```

I can't say if the actual Morse letters are correct. I found one error in your original (`C` and `K` are equal) that I corrected.

Comment: Grattis till 100k

Comment: Rather than `case 22: return 'D';    // -..`, perhaps a clever macro `case MORSE("-.."): return 'D';` and avoid getting the computation wrong.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica :-) Thank you! Yeah, a macro may do the trick. I'm not so fond of/used to them though. In c++ I'd make it a `constexpr` function.

Comment: Macro trick on a _string_ failed.  Another approach used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77648328/2410359).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's actually not as horrible as I expected it would need to be :-)

Answer (score 1):

Constructs such as `'.-'` are known as [*multicharacter constants*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant), which have implementation defined values (of type `int`). While providing a scalar value that can be used in a `switch` & `case`, they are hardly portable, and rarely used.

By contrast, `".-"` is a [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) (literal). As strings are not scalar values (rather comprised thereof), they cannot be used in a `switch` or `case`. To compare strings you can make use of [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) (or [`strncmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp)).

The loop

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
```

means this `switch`

```
switch (str[i])
```

is operating on a single character value at a time (one of `'.'`, `'-'`, or `'/'`).

You will need to *tokenize* your initial string into *substrings*. This can be done destructively with [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), or non-destructively with functions such as [`strspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn) / [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn).

Each substring can then be compared against every possible Morse code string to find the associated character.

---

Here is a cursory (incomplete) implementation using `strcspn` and `strncmp`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char morse_to_repr(const char *seg, size_t length)
{
    static const struct {
        char repr;
        const char *morse;
    } set[] = {
        { 'A', ".-" },
        { 'B', "-..." },
        /* ... and so on */
    };

    if (!length)
        return ' ';

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof set / sizeof *set); i++)
        if (0 == strncmp(set[i].morse, seg, length))
            return set[i].repr;

    return '?';
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = ".-/.-/.-";
    size_t offset = 0;

    /* until we reach the null-terminating character */
    while (string[offset]) {
        /* find the distance to the next delimiting character */
        size_t length = strcspn(string + offset, "/");

        putchar(morse_to_repr(string + offset, length));

        /* advance the position to the next delimiting character */
        offset += length;
        /* step over the delimiting character,
         * if it is NOT the null-terminating character */
        if (string[offset])
            offset++;
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

```
AAA
```

Comment: I've used strtok to break up my letters, I can print them out individually as Morse code but how do I compare the output of strtok to a string of letters to translate this?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which may help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LETTER_COUNT 4

// Size's of below arrays must be equal
const char *morse_codes[] = {".-","-..."};  
const char alphabet[] = {'A','B'};    

const int morse_code_size = sizeof(morse_codes)/sizeof(*morse_codes);

int main() {
  char str[] = ".-/-.../.-/-...";
  char result[MAX_LETTER_COUNT+1];
  const char delim = '/';

  char *token = strtok(str, &delim);
  int letterCount = 0;
  while(token != NULL) {
    for(int i=0;i<morse_code_size;i++) {
      // compare morse codes with substrings
      if(!strcmp(morse_codes[i], token)) {
        // if equal add alpahabet char to result array
        // and increase letter count
        result[letterCount] = alphabet[i];
        letterCount++;
      }
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, &delim);
  }

  result[letterCount] = '\0';
  printf("%s", result);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Case *can* switch on `'.-'` yet these are (multi-) *character constants* and not 2,3,4 character *strings*.  There are also a certainly a problem passed 4 characters, as needed with [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) characters like digits and punctuation.

It is challenging to portably form the matching constant from a sub-string.

An alternative, similar to [@Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77647496/2410359), is to form an index from the several `'.'`, `'-'` into an index and look up the ASCII character in a table rather than a `switch`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Morse code dit/dash to hash code.
#define M1(a)           ( 2 + ((a)=='-')* 1 + 0)
#define M2(a,b)         ( 4 + ((a)=='-')* 2 + M1((b)) - 2)
#define M3(a,b,c)       ( 8 + ((a)=='-')* 4 + M2((b),(c)) - 4)
#define M4(a,b,c,d)     (16 + ((a)=='-')* 8 + M3((b),(c),(d)) - 8)
#define M5(a,b,c,d,e)   (32 + ((a)=='-')*16 + M4((b),(c),(d),(e)) - 16)
#define M6(a,b,c,d,e,f) (64 + ((a)=='-')*32 + M5((b),(c),(d),(e),(f)) - 32)

// dit/dash string to hash code
int morse(size_t length, const char *s) {
  int m = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    m *= 2;
    switch (s[i]) {
      case '-':
        m++;
        break;
      case '.':
        break;
      default:
        return -1;
    }
  }
  m += 1 << (length + 0);
  return m;
}

// Table size <= 2^(5+1) or 64
static const char morse_table[] = { //
    // Letters
    [M2('.', '-')] = 'A', //
    [M4('-', '.', '.', '.')] = 'B', //
    [M4('-', '.', '-', '.')] = 'C', //
    [M3('-', '.', '.')] = 'D', //
    [M1('.')] = 'E', //
    [M4('.', '.', '-', '.')] = 'F', //
    [M3('-', '-', '.')] = 'G', //
    [M4('.', '.', '.', '.')] = 'H', //
    [M2('.', '.')] = 'I', //
    [M4('.', '-', '-', '-')] = 'J', //
    [M3('-', '.', '-')] = 'K', //
    [M4('.', '-', '.', '.')] = 'L', //
    [M2('-', '-')] = 'M', //
    [M2('-', '.')] = 'N', //
    [M3('-', '-', '-')] = 'O', //
    [M4('.', '-', '-', '.')] = 'P', //
    [M4('-', '-', '.', '-')] = 'Q', //
    [M3('.', '-', '.')] = 'R', //
    [M3('.', '.', '.')] = 'S', //
    [M1('-')] = 'T', //
    [M3('.', '.', '-')] = 'U', //
    [M4('.', '.', '.', '-')] = 'V', //
    [M3('.', '-', '-')] = 'W', //
    [M4('-', '.', '.', '-')] = 'X', //
    [M4('-', '.', '-', '-')] = 'Y', //
    [M4('-', '-', '.', '.')] = 'Z', //
    // Digits
    [M5('.', '-', '-', '-', '-')] = '1', //
    [M5('.', '.', '-', '-', '-')] = '2', //
    [M5('.', '.', '.', '-', '-')] = '3', //
    [M5('.', '.', '.', '.', '-')] = '4', //
    [M5('.', '.', '.', '.', '.')] = '5', //
    [M5('-', '.', '.', '.', '.')] = '6', //
    [M5('-', '-', '.', '.', '.')] = '7', //
    [M5('-', '-', '-', '.', '.')] = '8', //
    [M5('-', '-', '-', '-', '.')] = '9', //
    [M5('-', '-', '-', '-', '-')] = '0', //
    };

long morse_convert(size_t size, char ascii[size], const char *morse_string) {
  if (size == 0) {
    return -1;  // Size too small.
  }
  size--;
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    size_t offset = strspn(morse_string, ".-");
    if (offset == 0) {
      ascii[i] = '\0'; // No dot/dash pattern found.
      return -1;
    }
    int m = morse(offset, morse_string);
    if (m < 0 || (unsigned) m >= sizeof morse_table / sizeof morse_table[0]) {
      ascii[i] = '\0'; // Not in table
      return -1;
    }
    ascii[i] = morse_table[m];
    if (ascii[i] == 0) {
      return -1; // No matching character.
    }
    morse_string += offset;
    if (*morse_string == '\0') {
      i++;
      break;
    }
    if (*morse_string != '/') {
      ascii[i] = '\0'; // Unexpected separator.
      return -1;
    }
    morse_string++;
  }
  ascii[i] = '\0';
  if (*morse_string) {  // Destination too small.
    return -1;
  }
  return (long) i;
}
```

Test

```
int main(void) {
  char str[] = ".-/-.../-.-./-.././..-./--./..../../.---/"
      "-.-/.-../--/-./---/.--./--.-/.-./.../-/"
      "..-/...-/.--/-..-/-.--/--../"
      ".----/..---/...--/....-/...../-..../--.../---../----./-----";
  char dest[sizeof str / 2 + 1];
  int len = morse_convert(sizeof dest, dest, str);
  if (len < 0) {
    puts("Error");
  } else {
    printf("<%s>\n<%s>\n", str, dest);
  }
}
```

Output

```
<.-/-.../-.-./-.././..-./--./..../../.---/-.-/.-../--/-./---/.--./--.-/.-./.../-/..-/...-/.--/-..-/-.--/--../.----/..---/...--/....-/...../-..../--.../---../----./----->
<ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890>
```

Comment: I see a more compact form for encoding as N- dit/dah using 1 + N bits.  Will consider.

Answer (score 0):

The illegitimacy of attempting to use a C string (an array) as the token of a `case` has been covered sufficiently in other answers.

Back in the day, to avoid 'n' discrete assignment statements, it was up to the coder to pre-compute translations such as "Morse code character sequence to integer value." With that mapping done, one (or two) look-up tables could be entered into code and tested. Below is the result of such an effort.

Both functions use loops to either convert a bit pattern for an ASCII character to the string of dots & dashes that is its Morse counterpart, or decompose a string of dots & dashes to a bit pattern that is the index of a particular ASCII character. The OP is looking for the `unmorsify()` version.

Note: In Morse, a single space separates message characters and a triple space separates words. `strtok()` will NOT allow one to distinguish these two cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *morsify( char c ) {
    unsigned char oct[] = {
//  NUL  SOH  STX  ETX  EOT  ENQ  ACK  BEL   BS   HT   LF   VT   FF   CR   SO   SI
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,

//  DLE  DC1  DC2  DC3  DC4  NAK  SYN  ETB  CAN   EM  SUB  ESC   FS   GS   RS   US
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,

//   SP    !    "    #    $    %    &    '    (    )    *    +    ,    -    .    /
    001,0153,0122,   0,0211,   0, 050,0136, 066,0155,   0, 052,0163,0141,0125, 062,

//    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    :    ;    <    =    >    ?
    077, 057, 047, 043, 041, 040, 060, 070, 074, 076,0170,0152,   0, 061,   0,0114,

//    @    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N    O
   0132, 005, 030, 032, 014, 002, 022, 016, 020, 004, 027, 015, 024, 007, 006, 017,

//    P    Q    R    S    T    U    V    W    X    Y    Z    [    \    ]    ^    _
    026, 035, 012, 010, 003, 011, 021, 013, 031, 033, 034,   0,   0,   0,   0, 045,

//    `    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k    l    m    n    o
      0, 005, 030, 032, 014, 002, 022, 016, 020, 004, 027, 015, 024, 007, 006, 017,

//    p    q    r    s    t    u    v    w    x    y    z    {    |    }    ~  DEL
    026, 035, 012, 010, 003, 011, 021, 013, 031, 033, 034,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    };

    uint8_t at = 0, morse = oct[ c ], m = 0x80;
    while( m && !(m & morse) ) m >>= 1;
    static char obuf[10];
    for( m >>= 1; m ; m >>= 1 )
        obuf[ at++] = "-."[!(m & morse)];
    obuf[ at ] = '\0';

    return obuf;
}

char *unmorsify( char *cp, char *c ) {
    char rev[] = {
        'x', ' ', 'E', 'T', 'I', 'A', 'N', 'M',  // 00
        'S', 'U', 'R', 'W', 'D', 'K', 'G', 'O',
        'H', 'V', 'F',   0, 'L',   0, 'P', 'J',  // 02
        'B', 'X', 'C', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q',   0,   0,
        '5', '4',   0, '3', ',', '_',   0, '2',  // 04
        '&',   0, '+',   0,   0,   0,   0, '1',
        '6', '=', '/',   0,   0,   0, '(',   0,  // 06
        '7',   0,   0,   0, '8',   0, '9', '0',
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  // 10
          0,   0,   0,   0, '?',   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0, '"',   0,   0, '.',   0,   0,  // 12
          0,   0, '@',   0,   0,   0,'\'',   0,
          0, '-',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  // 14
          0,   0, ';', '!',   0, ')',   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0, ',',   0,   0,   0,   0,  // 16
        ':',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  // 20
          0, '$',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  // 21
    };

    uint8_t m = 0x01; // seed
    while( *cp && ( *cp == '.' || *cp == '-' ) )
        m = (uint8_t)( (m << 1) + (*cp++ == '-') ); // dash is hi bit
    *c = rev[m];
    return cp;
}

int main( void ) {
    char *str =
        "'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves "
        "Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:";
    char obuf[2048], *at = obuf;

    puts( str );
    for( ; *str; str++ )
        if( *str == ' ' )
            at += sprintf( at, "  " );
        else
            at += sprintf( at, "%s ", morsify( *str ) );
    puts( obuf );

    getchar();

    for( char *cp = obuf; *cp; ) {
        if( cp[0] == ' ' )
            if( cp[1] == ' ' && cp[2] == ' ' ) {
                putchar( ' ' );
                cp += 3;
                continue;
            }
            else
                cp++;

        char c;
        cp = unmorsify( cp, &c );
        putchar( c );
    }
    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
.----. - .-- .- ...   -... .-. .. .-.. .-.. .. --. --..--   .- -. -..   - .... .   ... .-.. .. - .... -.--   - --- ...- . ...   -.. .. -..   --. -.-- .-. .   .- -. -..   --. .. -- -... .-.. .   .. -.   - .... .   .-- .- -... . ---...

'TWAS BRILLIG, AND THE SLITHY TOVES DID GYRE AND GIMBLE IN THE WABE:
```

As this uses only simple, low-level C code, my expectation is that the reader does not need it commented. Happy to answer any questions you may have, though.

It should be noted that there are subtle variations of Morse code. Adapting this "coder unfriendly" version may be an effort. It works as well as it works, but requires focus and meticulous testing if/when changes might be required.